# Why is this text on line?

Tags: c, timestamp, printf

I have this code for create timestamp:
the code is in C.

```
void timestamp()
{
    time_t ltime; /* calendar time */
    ltime=time(NULL); /* get current cal time */
    printf("%s Something\n",asctime( localtime(&ltime) ) );
}
```

why is the text "Something" on the next line? What can I do to have it on same line?
I'm confused because I don't have \n after %s, so it should be on same line, but it isn't.
Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `asctime` specification (C99 §7.23.3.1/2) reads as follows:

> ```
> #include <time.h>
> char *asctime(const struct tm *timeptr);
> ```
>
> The asctime function converts the broken-down time in the structure pointed to by
>   `timeptr` into a string in the form
>
> ```
> Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0
> ```

Note the newline character at the end of the time.

If you do not want the time followed by a newline, you need to remove the newline yourself or use another library function, like `strftime`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out
**[asctime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/asctime/):**

> The string is followed by a new-line character ('\n') and the terminating null-character.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have a carriage return (`\n`) escape symbol after the word 'Something'? That would create a new line, which would place any following information on the next line, leaving 'Something' on its own line.

Comment: The problem he describes is that the time stamp is on the first line, while "Something" is printed on the second line.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the follow function to do a custom format, other conversions automatically add a newline:

[strftime function description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/)